# Replacing the class inside the tag with beautifulsoup to get new information

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

When I click on the "+" botton on the website, it will show me the hiding content, and simultaneously the class inside the tag will change from

```
<li class="acalog-course">
```

to

```
<li class="acalog-course acalog-course-open">
```

Is there a way to get the information after clicking on the website by changing the class with beautifulsoup? Thanks in advance!

Comment: If it's javascript driven then it's difficult to get it without analysing the website

Comment: Can you share the URL?

Comment: https://catalog.cofc.edu/preview_program.php?catoid=13&poid=2778&hl=%22data+science%22&returnto=search  Thanks!